# How to access Slackbot custom responses via slack API?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Slack provides wonderful slackbot custom responses. Is there any way to access these "when people say" and "slack bot response" data via slack API? Also is it possible to modify these via slack API?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, Slack does not provide any API to customize **SlackBot** responses using APIs.

Comment: So sad. Do you think they have any plan to add this?

Comment: AFAIK, no plans yet.

Comment: Could you add a quick json download link? We put many QA's there and we'd love to download them. Thanks!